# Multiple recurring BSODs after recent Windows update, most often 0x1A MEMORY_MANAGEMENT

Tags: bsod, windows-10-v1709

I've been getting BSODs for the past few months since a particular Windows update. Couldn't figure out what is causing it no matter what, having tried updated BIOS and drivers, as well as Memtest, `sfc /scannow`, `dism /restorehealth`, and `chkdsk` – the BSODs keep happening.

Recently, I've been able to make it happen by getting into any game (Dota 2, Destiny 2, Middle-earth: Shadow of War) and it would show a different BSOD each time with 0x1A `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT` happening the most. Other codes I've received include 0x109 `CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION`, 0x1C7 `STORE_DATA_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION`, 0x50 `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA`, and 0xEF `CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED`. However, after rebooting, I don't get any more BSODs until I manually shut the system down.

I downloaded the debugger, but have no idea what is happening, so any help would be very appreciated.

Here's my spec:

- Windows 10 version 1709, KB4041994
- Gigabyte GA-H170-D3H motherboard
- Intel Core i5-6600
- G.SKILL 16 GB DDR4-2400 memory
- Gigabyte AORUS GeForce GTX 1080 Ti Xtreme Edition graphics card
- Intel SSD 600p M.2
- WD Blue 1TB hard drive
- ASUS PCE-AC68 PCIe network adapter

---

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.15063.468 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be available.


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*C:\debug*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\debug*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
No .natvis files found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers.
No .natvis files found at C:\Users\ULTIMATE\AppData\Local\Dbg\Visualizers.
Windows 10 Kernel Version 16299 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 16299.15.amd64fre.rs3_release.170928-1534
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`d9084000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`d93e5fd0
Debug session time: Sat Oct 28 12:20:48.690 2017 (UTC + 8:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 14:45:01.331
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
...........................................................
Loading User Symbols
PEB address is NULL !
Loading unloaded module list
..........
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 1C7, {1, ffffd60f7b570000, bd2d5e4a, 211a25}

Probably caused by : ntkrnlmp.exe ( nt!SmHpBufferProtectEx+ea )

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

2: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

STORE_DATA_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION (1c7)
The store component detected a corruption in its data structures.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, Corruption ID.
Arg2: ffffd60f7b570000
Arg3: 00000000bd2d5e4a
Arg4: 0000000000211a25

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 401

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  16299.15.amd64fre.rs3_release.170928-1534

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  H170-D3H

SYSTEM_SKU:  Default string

SYSTEM_VERSION:  Default string

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  F23a

BIOS_DATE:  07/04/2017

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  H170-D3H-CF

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  x.x

DUMP_TYPE:  1

BUGCHECK_P1: 1

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffd60f7b570000

BUGCHECK_P3: bd2d5e4a

BUGCHECK_P4: 211a25

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: cf0

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 5e

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,5e,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: BA'00000000 (cache) BA'00000000 (init)

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1C7

PROCESS_NAME:  MemCompression

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  THE-BEAST

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  10-28-2017 12:23:47.0247

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.15063.468 amd64fre

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffff896b07bea0a8 -- (.exr 0xffff896b07bea0a8)
ExceptionAddress: 8a000002cc69a121
   ExceptionCode: d7b98963
  ExceptionFlags: 8a000002
NumberParameters: -143017629
   Parameter[0]: 8a000002f5e6e963
   Parameter[1]: 8a000002e489c963
   Parameter[2]: 8a00000305b9d121
   Parameter[3]: 8a000002dfe5e963
   Parameter[4]: 8a000002f6d9e963
   Parameter[5]: 8a000002f029f121
   Parameter[6]: 003d222600000000
   Parameter[7]: 8a000002fa371121
   Parameter[8]: 003d422c00000000
   Parameter[9]: 003d55b000000000
   Parameter[10]: 003d55b000000000
   Parameter[11]: 0a000001529d8963
   Parameter[12]: 0a0000016c9d7963
   Parameter[13]: 0a000002de2d6963
   Parameter[14]: 0a000001a48d5963

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff801d92ed9d6 to fffff801d91e7960

STACK_TEXT:  
ffff820a`76cf6608 fffff801`d92ed9d6 : 00000000`000001c7 00000000`00000001 ffffd60f`7b570000 00000000`bd2d5e4a : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffff820a`76cf6610 fffff801`d92080e6 : 00000000`00211a25 00000000`00000075 00000000`00000002 fffff801`d9007d5f : nt!SmHpBufferProtectEx+0xea
ffff820a`76cf6670 fffff801`d92e5244 : ffff820a`76cf6750 ffff820a`76cf7ae0 00000000`00000001 fffff801`d909e7db : nt!SmHpChunkHeapProtect+0x179bc2
ffff820a`76cf66a0 fffff801`d91f82b3 : ffffd60f`50de0000 ffff820a`76cf6750 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : nt!SMKM_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::SmStUnhandledExceptionFilter+0x50
ffff820a`76cf66f0 fffff801`d91c623f : ffff820a`00000003 00000000`00000000 ffff820a`76cf1000 ffff820a`76cf8000 : nt!`SMKM_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::SmStWorkerThread'::`1'::filt$0+0x1b
ffff820a`76cf6720 fffff801`d91ee10d : 00000000`00000000 ffff820a`76cf68c0 ffff820a`76cf7698 00000000`0000002f : nt!_C_specific_handler+0x9f
ffff820a`76cf6790 fffff801`d909ed70 : 00000000`0000000b ffff820a`76cf7698 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000003 : nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0xd
ffff820a`76cf67c0 fffff801`d909f8f4 : ffff820a`76cf7698 ffff820a`76cf73e0 ffff820a`76cf7698 ffff820a`76cf7698 : nt!RtlDispatchException+0x430
ffff820a`76cf6eb0 fffff801`d91f32ce : ffff896b`07bea0a8 0000007f`ffffff11 ffff896b`07bea0b0 fffff801`d929eab5 : nt!KiDispatchException+0x144
ffff820a`76cf7560 fffff801`d91f2630 : ffff8944`b583df50 fffff801`d912f79c ffff8944`a2512d60 fffff801`d9093ebe : nt!KiExceptionDispatch+0xce
ffff820a`76cf7740 fffff801`d92e973d : ffffd60f`50de00e8 00000000`00023844 ffffd60f`00023844 00000000`00017426 : nt!KiRaiseAssertion+0xf0
ffff820a`76cf78d0 fffff801`d92e9b0b : 00000000`20022c54 ffff820a`76cf7969 ffffd60f`50de0050 00000000`00000000 : nt!ST_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::StDmPageRecordRemove+0xe1
ffff820a`76cf7900 fffff801`d92ed1ca : 00000000`00000000 ffffd60f`5b401de0 00000000`00000000 fffff801`d908e713 : nt!ST_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::StDmPageRemove+0x2eb
ffff820a`76cf79d0 fffff801`d9209894 : ffffd60f`50de0000 ffff820a`76cf7a98 00000000`00000001 ffffd60f`50dd9700 : nt!ST_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::StWorkItemProcess+0x386
ffff820a`76cf7a20 fffff801`d9092b51 : fffff801`00000000 fffff801`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!SMKM_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::SmStWorker+0x176d34
ffff820a`76cf7ae0 fffff801`d91674e7 : ffffd60f`50de0000 fffff801`d91ece55 fffff801`d7d60180 000000ed`bd9bbfff : nt!SMKM_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::SmStWorkerThread+0x11
ffff820a`76cf7b10 fffff801`d91ecef6 : fffff801`d7d60180 ffffd60f`50dd9700 fffff801`d91674a0 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x47
ffff820a`76cf7b60 00000000`00000000 : ffff820a`76cf8000 ffff820a`76cf1000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  c70cfbc105f0d66aefd4832b6aa25df0b27b8ce8

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  8c4e2c6a5688dafbdb17d0cab88b0963f383d642

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  82d14546c43bd06881f781d6d197c4c7f7ceb9cb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!SmHpBufferProtectEx+ea
fffff801`d92ed9d6 cc              int     3

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  f78440cc

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!SmHpBufferProtectEx+ea

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  59dc593b

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  ea

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x1C7_nt!SmHpBufferProtectEx

BUCKET_ID:  0x1C7_nt!SmHpBufferProtectEx

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x1C7_nt!SmHpBufferProtectEx

TARGET_TIME:  2017-10-28T04:20:48.000Z

OSBUILD:  16299

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  784

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2017-10-10 13:23:07

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  170928-1534

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs3_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.16299.15.amd64fre.rs3_release.170928-1534

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  462

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x1c7_nt!smhpbufferprotectex

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {b5c78eab-51f4-1aa4-db01-375266dd7c78}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

and a mini dump

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.15063.468 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\102817-30687-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*C:\debug*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\debug*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
No .natvis files found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers.
No .natvis files found at C:\Users\ULTIMATE\AppData\Local\Dbg\Visualizers.
Windows 10 Kernel Version 16299 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 16299.15.amd64fre.rs3_release.170928-1534
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`d9084000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`d93e5fd0
Debug session time: Sat Oct 28 12:20:48.690 2017 (UTC + 8:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 14:45:01.331
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
...........................................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
..........
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 1C7, {1, ffffd60f7b570000, bd2d5e4a, 211a25}

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for win32k.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for win32k.sys
Probably caused by : ntkrnlmp.exe ( nt!SmHpBufferProtectEx+ea )

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to add bugcheck analyses for more crashes? I'm not familiar with this particular error.

Comment: not sure if this is what u want,but i added a mini dump too

Comment: This seems to be the minidump for the same crash. Can you try an older dump so we can see if there's anything in common between the two? This will help us track down the cause of the problem.

Comment: how long have you run memtest?

Comment: overnight so i'd say at least 8 hrs

Comment: update BIOS, last one has stability improvements. also run RAM at 2133 Speed. maybe the board has issues running it at 2400